# Magento - Sort on date updated in category list.phtml

Tags: php, sorting, magento

I'm trying to set the sort order in the category view for magento.

In /app/design/frontend/template_name/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml the product category is called this way:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

Is there a possibility to sort this collection using e.g. the following? 
For the record, this doesn't work. ;)

```
->addAttributeToSort('updated_at','asc')->setOrder('updated_at', 'asc')
```

Thanks in advance,

Maarten

Comment: Any reason you can't use the admin options to set the default sort using an attribute, and populate the drop down with one or more attributes? Admin>System>Configuration>Catalog>Frontend>"Product listing sort by” and Admin>Catalog>Manage Categories>"Display Settings" tab.

Comment: @ahillman3 No, the only options over there are 'best value', 'title' and 'price'.

Comment: I'll look some more later, but you are going to need to investigate the code more, as those configurable options are overriding your hard coded sort in the page. Hopefully I'll have time tonight, or someone else can assist before I do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All I had to do was doing some SQL queries.

Set a frontend label for the sort-by attribute.

```
update eav_attribute set frontend_label = "Updated" where attribute_code = "updated_at"
```

Enable used_for_sort_by

```
update catalog_eav_attribute set used_for_sort_by = 1 where attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = "updated_at")
```

Set updated_at as standard sorting value (could also be done in back-end)

```
update core_config_data set value = "updated_at" where path = "catalog/frontend/default_sort_by"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a blog post that does what you want. There is additional coding required, but it will give you what you want with additional sorting capability.

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-category-page-product-sorting

Everything after the first section, starting with **Custom Product Sorting In Category Page** gives you the overrides and additional functions necessary for the new capability.

Let me know if you think something is missing, and require some more functionality.